# ObjectQuery, passing datetime in Where clause filter

Tags: c#, objectquery

How to pass in Date Time value here?

```
ObjectQuery<Item> _Query = ItemEntities.CreateQuery<Item>("Item");
_Query = _Query.Where("(it.StartDate >= 11/4/2009 5:06:08 PM)");
```

my sample code above does seem to work.

even with this

```
ObjectQuery<Item> _Query = ItemEntities.CreateQuery<Item>("Item");
_Query = _Query.Where("(it.StartDate >= \"11/4/2009 5:06:08 PM\")");
```

I got type cast error in EDM.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The following should work:

```
ObjectQuery<Item> _Query = ItemEntities.CreateQuery<Item>("Item");
_Query = _Query.Where("(it.StartDate >= DATETIME'11/4/2009 17:06:08')");
```

See the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb399176.aspx) for more information on literals in ESQL queries.

Comment: still doesnt work, that gives me this error "The argument types 'Edm.DateTime' and 'Edm.String' are incompatible for this operation., near WHERE predicate, line 6, column 15."

Comment: @Juvil: I've updated the code snippet to include the DATETIME qualifier which is needed to distinguish date/time literals from string literals.

Answer (score 5):

Unfortunately for me @pmarflee's answer does not work. I've found another solution corresponding to [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb399176.aspx):

> **The date part must have the format: YYYY-MM-DD**, where YYYY is a four
>   digit year value between 0001 and 9999, MM is the month between 1 and
>   12 and DD is the day value that is valid for the given month MM.
>
> **The time part must have the format: HH:MM[:SS[.fffffff]]**, where HH is
>   the hour value between 0 and 23, MM is the minute value between 0 and
>   59, SS is the second value between 0 and 59 and fffffff is the
>   fractional second value between 0 and 9999999. All value ranges are
>   inclusive. Fractional seconds are optional. Seconds are optional
>   unless fractional seconds are specified; in this case, seconds are
>   required. When seconds or fractional seconds are not specified, the
>   default value of zero will be used instead.
>
> There can be any number of spaces between the DATETIME symbol and the
>   literal payload, but no new lines.
>
> DATETIME'2006-10-1 23:11' 
> DATETIME'2006-12-25 01:01:00.0000000' --
>   same as DATETIME'2006-12-25 01:01'

And code itself:

```
DateTime dateTimeValue = DateTime.Now;
// ESQL DATETIME format MUST be <yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm> format                                 
_Query = _Query.Where(string.Format("(it.StartDate >= DATETIME'{0:yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm}')",dateTimeValue);
```

Comment: @Anatolli Can you please help me with this  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22247016/edm-datetime-coversion-javascript